# Getting guild and default channel ID

Tags: python, discord.py

Say I have this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = bot.get_guild(...)
  channel = guild.get_channel(...)
  #do something
```

How can I automatically get the guild_id and default_channel_id after inviting this bot to my server?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bot.guilds` to access all guilds that the bot is in, or `member.guild` to access the specific guild as @moinierer3000 commented below.

If you're then looking for a specific channel use [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

All you need is the name of the channel, because a 'default' is what you choose it to be, the guild itself gives you access to all the channels in the server.

```
channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
channel_id = channel.id
```

Comment: You also could use `member.guild` to get the guild where the new member joined

Comment: True! member.guild also doesnt require the iteration.